# Print the response of a GET to the same server in PHP

Tags: php

I have two files: test.php and query.php.
My server is lighttpd.

In test.php I want to echo the response to query.php request.

It doesn't work because Lighttpd is single threaded.

How can I do that?

Comment: $request =  'query.php'
$response = file_get_contents($request);
echo $response

Comment: It didnt work. Any help?

Comment: It didn't work is not a valid reason for Stack Overflow. Some effort must be given. Also we need error codes, etc.

Comment: Check out the answers below - they are quite diverse and I'm sure one of them will answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are truly trying to emulate a request to the page then you should either use something like CURL, or `file_get_contents`. If you are just trying to run the code in query.php, then consider including/requiring query.php and making a function/method call.

As a quick and dirty last option, you can always use an [output buffer](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) that captures the output of including query.php:

```
$original_get = $_GET;
$_GET = array('var1'=>1);
ob_start();
include 'query.php';
$query_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$_GET = $original_get;
echo $query_contents;
```

Comment: Can I do that with different parameters? like query.php?var1=1

Comment: I updated the code but in query.php $_REQUEST['var1'] is empty

Comment: Great! Yes changing `$_GET` does not automatically change `$_REQUEST`. Glad you got it to work!

Comment: How can I call query.php several times? I am calling just one and calling ob_get_contents multiple times doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

print_r($_GET); will dump the GET vars.

put `<?php print_r($_GET) ?>` into test.php. Then from query.php, go to

`/test.php?var1=val1&var2=val2`

test.php will echo that var1 = val1 and var2 = val2.

you can also try `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: I want to do a HTTP Get to query.php from test.php.

Comment: @complex857's answer is the one you want, then.

Comment: I want to print in test.php the results from query.php with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or the [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension to send HTTP requests.

It could be simple like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/query.php?a=b');
```

Comment: Can I set the server dynamically ? i.e. a php variable that holds 'http://localhost/'

Comment: I am under Lighttpd , which is single threaded. Is this really possible?

Comment: Of course, you can set it to any url you want, just be be careful if there's user input involved not, might need to use a whitelist of servers. Also on some host's allow_url_fopen configuration prevents file_get_contents() to open network urls.

Comment: Well, lighttpd doesn't run php directly in its main thread, your setup most likely uses some kind of a cgi/fcgi method to fork php processes, but if your installation somehow configured to only fork one of these then it will block until timeout.

Comment: How can I fix that? I am using php-cgi.exe

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is your setup look like, but if you are using mod_fastcgi you can set the `max-procs` config variable, or just not specify it and it will defaults to 4. http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModFastCGI